# #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h> file not found problem React Native ios

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native

Getting this error in React native Xcode for ios application

import React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h doesn't find the file for build configuration

[image: image of error]

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

Open 'Build Settings' for your project in Xcode , search 'Header Search Path'.

Double click next to 'Header Search Path', where other properties have a 'yes' or 'no'

Now add following to the "Header Search Path" (under Build Settings):

```
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React/Base
```

Don`t forget Make both of them recursive.

Comment: I tried adding this as well, but it doesn't work for me.